# How to change this api results to a Jtable format?

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, api

Can some please help me understand how to achieve this?

// The Query is done through an API & then the results are returned however they get clustered.

```
try {
    QBC qc = new QBC("user@gmail.com", "P@ssw0rd");
    Vector<Vector<String>> evec = new Vector<>(qc.doQuery("xyz","1", "5","4,5,6","10" ));
     String Results = evec.toString();
     jTextArea2.setText(Results);

    // Need to learn to print this data to table

} catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
}
```

---

The code works now after changes

```
   try {
            QBC qc = new QBC("user@gmail.com", "password", "https://domain.com/api/", "token");
            Vector<Vector<String>> evec = new Vector<>(qc.doQuery("bjp43iquh","1", "5","4,5,6","10" ));
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
            columnNames.addElement("Column1");
            columnNames.addElement("Column2");
            JTable table = new JTable(evec, columnNames);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
            Component add = jInternalFrame1.add( scrollPane );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
        }
    }
```

but get an exception now>>>>>>> java.lang.Class.CastException:java.util.HaskMap cannot be cast to java.util.Vactor<<<<<<<<<

Comment: Which table do you want to print that onto?

Comment: Jtable.. I am kinda loosing hope trying figure this out

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector<Vector<String>> evec = new Vector<>(qc.doQuery("xyz","1", "5","4,5,6","10" ));
```

Your data is returned in a Vector or Vectors. This is a perfect data structure for using a `JTable`.

```
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
columnNames.addElement("Column1");
columnNames.addElement("Column2");
...
JTable table = new JTable(evec, columnNames);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: No I am getting an error java.lang.Class.CastException:java.util.HaskMap cannot be cast to java.util.Vactor

Comment: Can you help me fix this? I have updated the question now with your code, it works but throws exception instead, there is no syntax error..

Comment: Accourding to your code you say you have a Vector of Vectors. According to the Exception it says you return a HashMap from the query. I can't help you don't know what data is return from the query. Your query is not part of the JDK so I can't help because I don't know what it does.